# URL Pattern Matching in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm hoping to write a program to match malicious URN's in a list of URI's. The problem is simple, but with only rudimentary Python skills, and even less knowledge of C++ and the like, I'm unsure where to start after google left me with little to work with. So if possible, a Python suggestion would be easiest for me to write with this little bit of guidance but I'll take what I can get.

Here's the scenario: I'll have a CSV of malicious webpages of the same malware campaign which often have some bits of static identifiers in their URI's. I need to compare some length (4-10 as an example) of characters in each string to each other string then output any matches. The part that I'm stuck on is how to take a list of 100 URLs and feasibly test each one.

Example:
uri1: hxxp://domain.name/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
uri2: hxxp://domain.name/0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-=

so the loop would compare abcd to 0123 then 1234, 3456, etc.. then bcde to 0123, etc... Obviously in this example nothing matches but it's easier to illustrate how I was expecting the code might work.

TLDR: How do I take 100 URI's and "creep" through each character of the strings without having 100+ arrays of 100-200 entries each?

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is some kind of function that given two strings, gives you pairs of *n* long substrings:

```
from collections import deque

def n_wise(s1, s2, length=4):
    i1=iter(s1)
    i2=iter(s2)
    x, y = deque(maxlen=length), deque(maxlen=length)
    for _ in range(length):
        x.append(next(i1))
        y.append(next(i2))
    yield ''.join(x), ''.join(y)
    for a, b in zip(i1, i2):
        x.append(a)
        y.append(b)
        yield ''.join(x), ''.join(y)
```

Then you can iterate over things to compare like this:

```
>>> for left, right in n_wise("abcdefghijk...", "0123456789..."):
        ...
```